# custom lists() method in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Laravel has a method returens a response like `key=>value` array.

```
    $users = User::lists('name', 'id')->all();
```

if I want to customize lists to return `key` as a combination of `name` and `username`, how shoud i code ?

I also tried

```
    $users = User::lists('name'.'username', 'id')->all();
```

but, it's not working :|

Is there an alternative method ?

Comment: And what do you want to be value for those keys?

Comment: i want the key value consists of 'name' and 'username' column, not only name ....

Comment: Ok key is name and username. But what with value? You know, array consists of `key`=>`value` ?;)

Comment: value will be the ID ...

Comment: If everything else fails go with array_walk

Comment: may i ask u to explain more ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no custom `pluck()` method (do not use `lists()` since it's deprecated).  But you can create your own helper or method using this code:

```
$allUsers = User::all();

$users = [];

foreach ($allUsers as $user) {
    $users[$user->id] = $user->name.' '.$user->username;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$users = User::lists('name', 'id');
```

Comment: can key parameter consists of 'name' and 'username' column ?

Comment: @Sami yes use username instead of id or any key can used

Comment: i want the value be the ID coluemn and key parameter be 'username'+'name'

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
$users = User::pluck('name','id');
```

As, in laravel 5.2.0 lists() method was deprecated, it was replaced by pluck method .